# QTableView ignores data when stylesheet is set

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I have a `QTableView` and want to style its items margin as well as give it different colors depending on its model value. However as soon as I set a style sheet it ignores my data for roles like `Qt.BackgroundRole`. My question is: how can I set a margin with dynamic background coloring. Here's my mwe:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush


class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    counter = 0
    COLORS = [QBrush(Qt.green), QBrush(Qt.red), QBrush(Qt.blue), QBrush(Qt.cyan)]

    def rowCount(self, *_):
        return 2

    def columnCount(self, *_):
        return 2

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return f'{index.row()} - {index.column()} - {self.counter}'
        elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            ind = (index.row() + index.column() * 2 + self.counter) % 4
            return self.COLORS[ind]

    def change(self):
        self.counter += 1
        self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(0, 0), self.index(2, 2))


# Setup
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
model = Model()
view = QTableView()
view.setModel(model)
view.show()

# This is the line that causes the headache, I want to define some margins,
# however once setting this stylesheet it ignores my data calls with
# role == Qt.BackgroundRole
if True:
    app.setStyleSheet('''
        QTableView::item {
            background-color: grey;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            min-height: 20px;
        }''')


# The timer simulates new data comming in. We want to color each cell according
# to the status of its value.
timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(model.change)
timer.start(500)
app.lastWindowClosed.connect(timer.stop)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When setting the stylesheet

[image: margin]

When not setting the stylesheet

[image: color]